# Download manager uri is returing a number instead of the file location in android

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver for android that is supposed to open an intent to a pdf i am downloading but when it opens up the intent it opens a blank pdf, when i debug it it's giving me content://downloads/all_downloads/431 as the location instead of the file, the 431 is the dowload number and increases each time i download the pdf, my receiver looks like this.

```
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
    val action = intent.action
    if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {

        
        val manager = context!!.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        val completeDownloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1)
        var uri: Uri? = manager.getUriForDownloadedFile(completeDownloadId)

        Log.d("BROADCASTEND", uri.toString())
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.data = uri
        MApplication.currentActivity.startActivity(intent)

    }
}
```

does anyone know why it opens a blank pdf and references the number instead of the file? i can see that it is downloading the pdf.

Comment: "i debug it it's giving me content://downloads/all_downloads/431 as the location instead of the file" -- that is perfectly normal. "when it opens up the intent it opens a blank pdf" -- you are not granting permission to access the content. Try adding `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to your `Intent`. Also, please get rid of `currentActivity` as a property, as you are leaking memory.

Comment: Thanks, yeah i had to grant it read permission, also il take a look into that thanks.